# How do you track a form submission once per session with Google Tag Manager (GTM)

Tags: javascript, cookies, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-ads-api

I'm currently trying to track form submissions on a site that has forms all over it as well as user accounts.  We want to track the first form submission (a new lead) then nothing else.  Because of the platform (I don't have access to the backend) it's causing every form submission to be tracked.   Is there a way to limit it to user or session?

In this instance I'm wanting to fire conversion pixels for adwords and it's firing every time a form is filled out.

I've looked at Simo's guide on this that was written 6 years ago but it doesn't seem to be working.

What I did as a stopgap is identify the most common single use form (the registration form) and use that as the conversion method.  However, there are other forms that are meant to be used by logged in users that get submitted over and over again.   If a non-logged-in user uses this form an account is automatically created.  These are the form submissions I'm trying to track.

Answer (score 1):

This depends a bit on your exact definition of session or user, but a possible workaround might be to simply use Google Ads' option to create a conversion that is only counted once per click:

[image]

That way, only the first form submission would actually be counted as a conversion in Google Ads no matter how many pixels were fired.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  Sadly the ads setting is set to one.

Comment: And you're seeing multiple of those conversions for a single click in Google Ads? That's certainly not expected behavior...

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a [goal](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1012040?hl=en) - form submission based on events sent via GTM. Achieving a particular goal is only possible once per session, so it seems like an appropriate solution.

But it only limits it to sessions. So if a user sents 2 forms within different sessions, the goal will be reached 2 times.

the user-based approach requires some additional workarounds due to the fact that GA is not a user-based system itself.

Comment: Goals are great for that purpose.  In this instance I'm wanting to fire conversion pixels for adwords and it's firing every time a form is filled out.